# expire refresh_token after new access_token has been used

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

We are using the `gopkg.in/oauth2.v3` package to provide an oauth2 API for our clients. Authorization code flow is used and in the end they have an access_token with an expiration time and a refresh token.

I'm using the default `manage.Manager` an access_token is invalidated when the refresh_token is used. We do however worry that things can happen and that the client for some reason did not receive the new access_token. So we would only want to invalidate the refresh token when the new access_token has been used (so we are sure that they received it).

We even use the same API to integrate with Google Home (actions) and in their testing they complain about this. So it feels weird that a Google service is complaining about the oauth2 functionality of a Google-created oauth2 library.

Is there any straightforward way of achieving this? The `RefreshingConfig` has two fields, `IsRemoveAccess` and `IsRemoveRefreshing`. From what I can tell, having any of them as true will mean that the old access_token is removed when being refreshed.

Are there any other settings that I've missed? Or do I have to come up with this functionality myself.